# CTE Invalid column name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I am completely stuck on this one.  I looked in the other questions, but could not find one that answered this (that I could understand, anyway).  I have the following CTE in my query but MaxUserID is squiggled red in the 3 places it's used with an "invalid column name 'MaxUserID'" error.  The column it should represent is an int, if that helps.   Any advice?

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

```
;with TotalCount(TotalCount,MaxUserID)

as

(
    Select ISNULL(count(distinct uCPR.HeaderID), 0) as TotalCount, MaxUserID
            from ClientFeedback.dbo.UnitCountCPR uCPR
            where 
                uCPR.DHDate between @StartDate and @EndDateMod
                and uCPR.TargetID in (@StatusID)
                and uCPR.UserID = MaxUserID
                and uCPR.DTStamp between @StartDate and @EndDateMod
                and uCPR.ClientID in (@ClientID)
      group by MaxUserID

)
```

Comment: Does the column MaxUserID actually exist in the table UnitCountCPR?

Comment: Have you tried running it?  Sometimes intellisense (which makes the red underline) is out-of-sync with the db structure as well.  You can manually refresh it with `CTRL+SHIFT+R`

Comment: MaxUserID does not exist in the table.

I did try running it, giving me the errors.  I did not refresh intellisense though.

Comment: If MaxUserID does not exist in UnitCountCPR you cannot select it.

Comment: What do you want to put into `MaxUserID` ?? Obviously, it's not present in the database table - so what did you intend to return for MaxUserID ??

Answer (score 1):

Refresh your intellisense cache, and then use your table alias to pick the coluumns.  Also, count will never be null, your IsNull isn't doing you any good. And is there a reason you are using in instead of equals?

Comment: I'll try that when I get in tomorrow but given I was at it for 14 hours, that sounds reasonable.  I need in because it's coming from an SSRS report as a multiselect parameter.  I'll get rid of the isnull though, thanks for the help.